# Things are slower with "dplyr" is there a faster way?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I m just trying to calculate the relative angle between with my x,y,z data frame to the reference vector. So far, I use `dplyr` to group things and apply my `angle` function to get relative angle. However things are quite slow even for dummy data that I provide here.

```
set.seed(12345)

x <- replicate(1,c(replicate(1000,rnorm(50,0,0.01))))
y <- replicate(1,c(replicate(1000,rnorm(50,0,0.01))))
z <- replicate(1,c(replicate(1000,rnorm(50,0.9,0.01))))
ref_vector <- data.frame(ref_x=rep(0,100),ref_y=rep(0,100),ref_z=rep(1,100)) 
set <- rep(seq(1,1000),each=50)

data_rep <- data.frame(x,y,z,ref_vector,set)
```

>

```
head(data_rep)
#           x            y         z ref_x ref_y ref_z set
#    1  0.005855288 -0.015472796 0.9059337     0     0     1   1
#    2  0.007094660 -0.013354359 0.9040137     0     0     1   1
#    3 -0.001093033 -0.014661486 0.9047502     0     0     1   1
#    4 -0.004534972 -0.002764655 0.9070553     0     0     1   1
#    5  0.006058875 -0.008339952 0.8926551     0     0     1   1
#    6 -0.018179560 -0.008412400 0.9055541     0     0     1   1
```

I define the angle between two vectors with this `angle` function,

```
angle <- function(x,y){
  dot.prod <- x%*%y 
  norm.x <- norm(x,type="2")
  norm.y <- norm(y,type="2")
  theta <- acos(dot.prod / (norm.x * norm.y))
  as.numeric(theta)
}
```

then lets apply this to our `data_rep`

```
library(dplyr)
system.time(df_angle <- data_rep%>%
  rowwise()%>%
  do(data.frame(.,angle_rad=angle(unlist(.[1:3]),unlist(.[4:6]))))%>%
  group_by(set)%>%
  mutate(angle=angle_rad*180/pi, mean_angle=mean(angle)))

#     user  system elapsed 
#      64.22    0.08   64.81 
#    Warning message:
#    Grouping rowwise data frame strips rowwise nature
```

As you can see, the process took around 1 min and I even did not provide all my real data set which has 350000 rows and it takes 10 min to calculate the relative angle.

I wonder is there any way to speed up this process.

Thanks!

Comment: `rowwise()` tends to be very slow. If you can, find someway of calculating what you need in `angle()` so that it doesn't need unlisting in your dplyr chain. I think the problem in `angle()` is that you calculate two matrices (the two `norm()`s). If, somehow, you can do these steps differently, then you should be ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make a simple `mutate`statement instead of your `do(data.frame())` part. This improves the performance quite a bit, because you no longer have to convert each row into a `data.frame`

```
system.time(df_angle2 <- data_rep%>%
              rowwise() %>% 
              mutate(angle_rad=angle(x = c(x,y,z),y = c(ref_x,ref_y,ref_z))) %>%
              group_by(set)%>%
              mutate(angle=angle_rad*180/pi, mean_angle=mean(angle)))

##      user      system     elapsed 
##      3.72        0.00        3.71

all.equal(df_angle,df_angle2)
##   TRUE
```

Answer (score 22):

Just discover linear algebra for yourself:

```
m1 = as.matrix(data_rep[, 1:3])
m2 = as.matrix(data_rep[, 4:6])

system.time( {
  m1 = m1 / sqrt(rowSums(m1 ^ 2))
  m2 = m2 / sqrt(rowSums(m2 ^ 2))  
  RESULT <- acos(rowSums(m1 * m2))
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.004   0.001   0.006 
all.equal(df_angle$angle_rad, RESULT)
# TRUE
```